# eBay Trading API PHP XML call fails (Ack failure)

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

So I can't seem to get this code working.  I used a very similar code under the Finding API that works great, made the appropriate changes (endpoint, header, etc.) for the Trading API, and now it won't work.  In using the eBay API Test Tool, everything seems fine, so I'm not sure what the issue may be.

Can anyone provide insight?  The ack returns failure instead of success.  My PHP has curl enabled and that is not the issue either.  Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // Turn on all errors, warnings, and notices for easier debugging

// API request variables
$endpoint = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';  // URL to call
$query = 'username';                  // Supply your own query keywords as needed

// Construct the findItemsByKeywords POST call
$resp = simplexml_load_string(constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query));

// Check to see if the call was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
  $results = '';  // Initialize the $results variable

  // Parse the desired information from the response
  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
    $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
    $price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;    
    $title = $item->title;

    // Build the desired HTML code for each searchResult.item node and append it to $results
    $results .= "<tr><td><img src=\"$pic\"></td><td>$price</td><td><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></td></tr>";
  }
}
else {  // If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
  $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful.";
}

?>

<!-- Build the HTML page with values from the call response -->
<html>
<head>
<title>eBay Search Results for <?php echo $query; ?></title>
<style type="text/css">body { font-family: arial,sans-serif;} </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>eBay Search Results for <?php echo $query; ?></h1>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $results;?>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

<?php

function constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $query) {
  global $xmlrequest;

  // Create the XML request to be POSTed
  $xmlrequest  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "<GetBidderListRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "<RequesterCredentials>\n <eBayAuthToken>xxxxxxxxxxx</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "<UserID>";
  $xmlrequest .= $query;
  $xmlrequest .= "</UserID>\n";
  $xmlrequest .= "</GetBidderListRequest>";

  // Set up the HTTP headers
  $headers = array(
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:951',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:xxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:xxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:xxxxxxxxxx',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:0',
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GetBidderList'
  );

  $session  = curl_init($endpoint);                       // create a curl session
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);              // POST request type
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    // set headers using $headers array
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlrequest); // set the body of the POST
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    // return values as a string, not to std out

  $responsexml = curl_exec($session);                     // send the request
  curl_close($session);                                   // close the session
  return $responsexml;                                    // returns a string

}  // End of constructPostCallAndGetResponse function

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fault is in the line `if ($resp->ack == "Success") {`. The correct field name is [Ack](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetBidderList.html#Response.Ack). Fields in the Trading API are in a different case to those found in the Finding API. Changing the code to `if ($resp->Ack == "Success") {` should work.

Comment: I tried both upper and lowercase Ack and ack, didn't make a difference.

Comment: You can use the following to see what errors eBay are returning in the response.

foreach ($resp->Errors as $error) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", $error->ShortMessage);
}

Comment: Tried that and no luck either.  The code seems to be failing in the curl section, even though curl is enabled.  I had another guy look at it and he couldn't figure it out either.  For now, my workaround is running the API Tool on eBay, then copying the output as a .xml file and running the top half of this code to generate an output.  It's a bit more manual but it is able to at least get me the data I'm seeking from the API.